# How to make <li> to auto resize according to its content?

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how to dynamically resize the width of these `<li>`s according to their text content, so that it doesn't span across the entire web page? I use `with: auto;` but that doesn't do the job.

```css
li {
    list-style: none;
    background: #4FBAF7;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
    <li>Fifth 5th</li>
    <li>Sixth 6th</li>
    <li>Seventh</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you need line break after each li?

Comment: Yes I do I need it to be in its line break position. I don't want the `display: inline` @sdcr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to set `li {display:table;}` -  "shrink-to-fit" width.

```css
li {
    background: #4FBAF7;
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
    <li>Fifth 5th</li>
    <li>Sixth 6th</li>
    <li>Seventh</li>
</ul>
```

You could also use the `float` + `clear` approach (suggested in the comments below).

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: auto;
}
li {
    background: #4FBAF7;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
    <li>Fifth 5th</li>
    <li>Sixth 6th</li>
    <li>Seventh</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
li {
       list-style: none;
       background: #4FBAF7;
        width:intrinsic;

}
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm talking about! Thanks man! By the way, is it fully supported across browsers? @Mark

Comment: @PopoD'Angelo - [Support is patchy, there is no support in IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width). You can [read more about the various browser values here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#max-content). The `intrinsic` value is the non standard webkit version of the `max-content` value.

Comment: It's a new CSS3 feature so when all browsers (basically just IE now) start supporting CSS3 then this will be included.

Comment: Thanks for the links and the answer! I appreciate that! @misterManSam

Answer (score 0):

This is also a possibility (although not yet supported fully, according to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=fit-content)):

```
li {
    width: fit-content
}
```